# ASP.NET Core MVC anti forgery

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken

Trying to turn on anti forgery in core mvc project but with no luck. What was done:

Filter added to automatically check anti forgery token on every POST request.

```
services.AddMvc(o =>
{
  o.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});
```

Token generation was added to each page this way.

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Antiforgery;
@{
   var antiforgeryRequestToken = Antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
}
...
...
<script>
    var antiforgeryToken = @Json.Serialize(antiforgeryRequestToken);
</script>
```

And finally each client ajax request adds `RequestVerificationToken` this way.

```
var options = {
        url: o.url, type: 'POST', data: o.params, headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': antiforgeryToken } };
```

I can see each ajax request has the token but I am always getting 400 for any POST request. If I disable the filter, it works fine. But once I enable it, asp.net core starts verification on each POST request and it always returns me 400.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I've followed the instructions I got in the comments and now the code looks like following. ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddMvc(o => { 
  o.Filters.Add(new HandleAllExceptionsFilterFactory()); 
  o.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()); 
}); 

services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.CookieName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

And here is the middleware registered:

```
app.Use(next => context => { 
if (context.Request.Path == "/") 
{ 
    var antiforgery = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IAntiforgery>(); 
    var token = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context); 
    context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", token.RequestToken, new CookieOptions {HttpOnly = false}); 
} 

return next(context); 
});
```

I also removed any client side javascript code that has been sending the header before. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: it should be `data: {   __RequestVerificationToken: antiforgeryToken  }`

Comment: do you mean the header name must be changed from `RequestVerificationToken ` to `__RequestVerificationToken`?

Comment: not only, token should be in `data`. try if it'll work.

Comment: do I still have to change the header name?

Comment: yes, change it to `__RequestVerificationToken`

Comment: no, it doesn't work

Comment: take a look at [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Antiforgery/issues/29)

Comment: Well, thank you. But this is about ASP.NET 5, however I am talking about Core version (i. e. ASP.NET 6)

Comment: ASP.NET 6 does not exist in Universe, [ASP.NET 5 is now ASP.NET Core 1.0](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx). It's MVC 6 not ASP.NET 6

Comment: You are right, it seems my issue is to regenerate token after user sign in. How can I force anti forgery to regenerate the token?

Comment: refer [this answer](https://github.com/aspnet/Antiforgery/issues/29#issuecomment-165304489). Let me know if that'll work.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your idea.
The point is I am generating and saving token in cshtml this way: 
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Antiforgery;
@{
    var antiforgeryRequestToken = Antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
}

Comment: And I am using the `antiforgeryRequestToken` variable to insert it into request header.

Comment: So, since my first authentication post request works fine but any other request after authentication is not working it seems I need to regenerate token after authentication. The question is how can I do token regeneration taking into account the way I am generating it on my pages?

Comment: I get. with above answer there is not need to manually generate token in razor view. instead, on response, you'll send `"XSRF-TOKEN"` cookie, where token will be placed and request from client side will send that token automatically to server.

Comment: Step 2 is unclear: "Angular will send back ...". I am not using Angular, does it mean I have to set the header manually?

Comment: No, that information is stored in cookie, so whatever you use to send a http request that information will be part of it.

Comment: Now even first authentication request is returning 400.
Here is the ConfigureServices code:
`services.AddMvc(o =>
            {
                o.Filters.Add(new HandleAllExceptionsFilterFactory());
    o.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
            });

            services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");`

Comment: Here is a middleware code:

```app.Use(next => context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path == "/")
                {
                    var antiforgery = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IAntiforgery>();
                    var token = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                    context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", token.RequestToken,
                        new CookieOptions {HttpOnly = false});
                }
                return next(context);
            });```

Comment: And here is a cookie value for authorization page:
```Cookie:Session=7d2a537b-6510-4697-aefc-256ffb57f5f6; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.vyEDvgUpsG4=CfDJ8Bklbo1cCuxPmsBZX7rsdNkHrBne6QrHph5XhA2hGk7SdjgWLokQM6brAC0qdN1WGI5PJa_FDLbzkkjbu_Rp7QNrDp3snAhejLBhIeXXTMUvm162UwHOMsrRrtwU6CHeOxyRky4bcaS7PCTcyKOZhKY; XSRF-TOKEN=CfDJ8Bklbo1cCuxPmsBZX7rsdNmom9EH_NjkH0qgfA5gtsODCyL1HeaWb4Sfo5P9UPxu6bXTI_AnHvYvnSboKu6vKIWvzbInmLBopzFn0rnbjujvikCEP2w6xgAumpxebG1EEaK_VfbkkAJNod5gfcUwcUo; G_AUTHUSER_H=0```

Comment: Now I can't even authorise user. But it was working before.

Comment: Ok, it seems I've configured antiforgery to check for header but should configure it to check for cookie value. Did it, but still doesn't work

Comment: Could you update the questions with the latest version for your code based on the comments?

Comment: Just updated the example.

Answer (score 12):

You're close, it's much simpler than you think it is.

First off, when you use `services.AddMvc();` anti-forgery is already added. There's no need to add any filters, so remove those.

Then you'll want to change your anti-forgery configuration.

```
// Old
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.CookieName = "XSRF-TOKEN"); 
// New
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

This is only required if you are using ajax. By default the anti-forgery system will only consider form data.

Next, in your views you can easily generate an anti-forgery token by using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`. There's no need for all that extra code. You can get rid of it. This will create a hidden `<input />` with the value of the token. If your using a `<form />` this will automatically be created for you if you use tag helpers such as `asp-action` and `asp-controller`. If you don't use those tag helpers you can use then use `asp-antiforgery="true"`.

Now your ajax request can consume the hidden `<input />` value. Here's an example:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/api/test",
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    statusCode: {
        200: function () {
            alert("Success");
        },
        400: function () {
            alert("Client error");
        },
        500: function () {
            alert("Server error");
        }
    }
});
```

The important part is the `beforeSend` function. This is where you set the request header to the same header name in you setup in `Startup.cs`

Now all you need to do is add `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` to the method you want.

Finally before you test be sure to remove the middleware you added.

This is only one way to do it. There are many other solutions found at the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery).

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. The point is I have the token generation in my markup in shared view. We have SPA application and the shared view is not being reloaded after user sign in. That is why I need to regenerate it manually. Using your approach there will be old token value in the input field generated before user sign in.

Comment: Oh, this is an SPA app? Would of been nice to know before hand. No worries though. Are you using Angular, React, Vue, etc.?

Comment: Yes, this is SPA.

Comment: Solution worked great, only change I had to make for .net core 2.0 was to set the header to "X-XSRF-TOKEN" rather than "XSRF-TOKEN"

Comment: @JamesBlake Why do you need to change the header name?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both cookies have the same path:
[image]

You can change this in your antiforgery configuration options. If you are using fetch to make your calls make sure too that your are sending cookies including the credentials header.